# Is there any way to install matplotlib in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way for Matplotlib to be installed in Python 3.3? After using pip to try and install it, I am unable to get it installed as matplotlib uses Python 3.4. I was wondering if there was any earlier version of matplotlib that is compatible with python 3.3?

Comment: I've checked matplotlib version 1.4.3 works with python 3.3 use pip install matplotlib==1.4.3

Comment: Use "pip3 install matplotlib" to install lib on third version of python

Comment: If you can upgrade your Python version, that would be better. Python 3.3 reached end-of-life in September 2017, so doesn't even receive security fixes at this point. Is there a reason that you have to use Python 3.3?

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri do you know the required dependencies for it?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Have to use it for compatibility with a tutor unfortunately.

Comment: don't think matplotlib has any dependencies and it will show during installation the packages it might want to upgrade so you can know which were upgraded if needed to be downgraded later.

Comment: Reading [what's new in python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) I don't see anything special which would prevent you and your tutor both upgrading to 3.4. It does not look as if it would break anything.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm using PyQt4 and as far as I'm aware I'd have to use PyQt5 in 3.6.4, therefore I would have to change a large chunk of my code just to upgrade

Comment: I think PyQt4 [is available for python 3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/).